# Integrate exponential to the power of the square root term

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have the following integral to compute:

\begin{align}
  &C = \int^\infty_{-\infty} \exp\left(-\sqrt{cb+cx^2} +\sqrt{cb}\right) dx\\
  &  = \exp\left(\sqrt{cb}\right) \int^\infty_{-\infty} \exp\left(-\sqrt{cb+cx^2} \right) dx.
\end{align}

Using integration by substitution, let $z=\sqrt{cb+cx^2}$ then $\frac{dz}{dx}=cx(cb+cx^2)^{-1/2}$, and $x = \left( \frac{z^2-cb}{c} \right)^{1/2}$. Then we have

\begin{align}
   C &= \exp\left(\sqrt{cb}\right) \int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{-z} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{cb+cx^2}}{cx}dz\\
     &= \frac{\exp\left(\sqrt{cb}\right)}{\sqrt{cb}} \int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{z}{\sqrt{z^2-cb}} e^{-z} dz.
\end{align}

I am not sure how to compute this integral further. Can you suggest any useful tip or advice on this please?

Also, the equation above is same as in [Li et. al. (2020)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11704-019-9097-x) with $c=\zeta$ and $b=\beta$. I have a feeling that the solution to the integral above may include the modified Bessel function of the second kind since equation (5) of [Li et. al. (2020)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11704-019-9097-x) has the $K_1(\zeta\beta)$ term. So, I am trying to achieve the same normalising constant as that in equation (5).

EDIT: I made some minor error in my computations. Since this function is symmetric around the origin, the integral should be
\begin{align}
  &C = \exp\left(\sqrt{cb}\right) \int^\infty_{-\infty} \exp\left(-\sqrt{cb+cx^2} \right) dx\\
& = 2\exp\left(\sqrt{cb}\right) \int^\infty_0 \exp\left(-\sqrt{cb+cx^2} \right) dx.
\end{align}
Let $z=cb+cx^2$ then $x = \sqrt{\frac{z-cb}{c}}$ and $\frac{dx}{dz} = \frac{1}{2c}\left( \frac{z-cb}{c} \right)^{-1/2}$. Then the integral becomes

\begin{align}
  C &= 2\exp\left(\sqrt{cb}\right) \int^\infty_{cb} \exp\left(-\sqrt{z} \right) \cdot \frac{1}{2c} \left( \frac{z-cb}{c} \right)^{-1/2} dz\\
&= \frac{ \exp\left(\sqrt{cb}\right)}{\sqrt{c}} \int^\infty_{cb} \frac{ \exp\left(-\sqrt{z} \right)}{\sqrt{z-cb}} dz. 
\end{align}

This integral should now be bounded and does not diverge. Any idea of how to compute this integral further?

Comment: When you changed the variable (with $z$), you forgot to update the integration bounds. Right now, your integral diverges because of that.

Comment: Wouldn't the integration bounds still be from minus infinity to positive infinity?

Comment: No, $z$ is the positive square root of a number, so it evolves between $0$ and $+\infty$. BTW, the transformed integral diverges.

Comment: Thank you, I have revised my computations since I realised i made some mistakes and now, the integral should be bounded.